# SVG / Raphael Issue with setting opacity in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, raphael

I'm facing a very odd issue here using Raphael.js to draw using SVG.  If I set opacity on a triangle I've drawn, it cuts off the corners.  It appears fine in Chrome and IE however.  Using the same triangle drawing, if I change opacity to 1 or if I alter `fill-opacity` instead of just `opacity`, it renders correctly.  Even more strange, creating a demo in jsFiddle using the same exact code and libraries renders fine.  I double checked versions of Raphael.js, updated mine again just in case, etc.

Does anyone have any idea how this could be happening?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
            var paper = Raphael(0,0, 800, 800);
            var triangle1 = paper.path('M295,738 l0,-738 l500,0 Z')
            var triangle2 = paper.path('M200,200 l0,-100 l100,0 Z')

            triangle1.attr({
                fill: '#fff',
                'opacity': '0.5'
            });

            triangle2.attr({
                fill: '#fff',
                opacity: 1,
                stroke: 'red'
            });
```

Here is the jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/crisp330/26PaS/

And here is what this looks like on my FF version 16.0.2:  http://grab.by/hBWK

I even directly copied the iFrame source from jsFiddle (which looks correct in FF for me), and pasted it into a new HTML page... nope!  Corners get cutoff again.

Any ideas as to whats going on?

Comment: If you go to your jsFiddle and zoom out with Ctrl + Scroll Wheel, does the triangle's corners get clipped for you? It seems like Firefox is not scaling the triangle properly. This may be related to your problem.

Comment: Works for me under the same settings and with the iframe source pasted directly into an html file loaded into FF16.0.2. Do you have any addons such as Stylish that might be preprocessing or otherwise affecting your SVG?

Comment: I don't have any plugins I can think of that would cause this.  For the time being at least, I ended up setting the fill opacity separately (luckily I did not end up needing any stroke) which did not cause the clipping issues.

Comment: @Ryan - Yes, the corners do get clipped on the fiddle when I Ctrl+Mousewheel, that's interesting.  I am pretty sure at the original time I was at a normal zoom setting when I was viewing it separately.  I'll have to double check on that and see if that was the case.